# Android : Event for selected spinner change

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have three items in a spinner on top of my view. Assume those three spinner items are city A, city B, and city C.

I have tab activity that contains 2 tab hosts. The first tab host contains a list view, and the second tab host contains a grid view of a calender.

The list view contains details about the specific city I retrieved from the server.
If I press the spinner and select city B, then I should update my list view with details about city B. Either of grid view of a calender.

The problem is how to get event pressed of selected spinner item, so that I can start new tab activity and update the list view.

I have tried starting the activity inside `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`, but it gives me a loop without ending. I have tried starting the activity inside `spinner.setOnItemClickListener`, but `spinner` does not support it yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ChangeEvent event like this:

```
private void init()
{
    spinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner();

    spinner.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener()
    {
        public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt)
        {
            spinnerChange(evt);
        }
    });
}

private void spinnerChange(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt)
{
    // Code for what to do when the spinner is changed
}
```